# JSON object or String resultset

Tags: ajax, json, api-design

I make an ajax call (very simple), that currently returns a string of html. Depending on who is calling it, this string can become very long at times. What I'd like to know is why it's better to return a JSON result and build my HTML afterwards, rather than just returning a long string.

Comment: Just read your statement twice _this string can become very long at times_

Comment: How long is long? You can retrieve complete websites using AJAX without a problem. Thats why its asynchronous!

Comment: Max character count so far about 12K, mostly less than this.

Answer (score 1):

Some advantages of returning JSON instead of HTML:

1. The data can be used as data for analysis or other uses, not just used for presentation.
2. JSON data is often/usually much smaller than the full presentation HTML so you are transferring less data over the internet.
3. You create a separation between data and presentation rather than mix them both into one single API.  Your server returns the data which a separate piece of code then turns into presentation.
4. The JSON data can be processed or modified more easily before presentation (such as filtered, sorted, tagged, expanded/collapsed, etc...).
5. You can use the same JSON data for many different types of presentation.  If you return HTML, the presentation is already baked in so if you want a different presentation, you then have to create a whole new AJAX call.

---

If you want an extreme way to think about this, then ask yourself why does a database return raw data and not an HTML view of the data?  It's because you can do so many more different kinds of things with the actual data so therefore the data is so much more useful by having it give you just the data and then different pieces of code to do something with the data (analyze it, combine it with other data, make decisions based on it, present it for viewing, etc....).  If the database only returned an HTML view of the data, it would be far harder to do all these other things with the data.  The same is true of an Ajax call which is really just the client's access to data.

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me guys. But my call is solely for presentation, no manipulation of the data required. Considering the client's browser which is more efficient to process a string of HTML or to process JSON. Or are we just going to hover over the fact that JSON is "smaller" to send over the internet

Comment: @I_understand_sometimes - if you're only looking at "efficiency", you'd have to define what you mean by that and then it would probably depend upon the exact makeup of the data and how big it was and how the presentation worked.  I'd hazard a guess that you couldn't tell the difference from the browser if it was done either way.  FYI, good programming design doesn't just design the minimum required for the current design, but designs things in a way that meet the current needs AND is designed in a way that can be used for many other possible things in the future (my point about using JSON).

Comment: @I_understand_sometimes - in gauging how flexible a design is, ask yourself how much work it would be if in a few weeks someone now wants to sort the data or filter the data or offer multiple presentations of it.  Which design direction would make that easier to add/change?

Comment: @I_understand_sometimes - here's one data point.  LinkedIn has just started moving to servers that produce JSON and then javascript in the browser renders DUST templates to form the HTML presentation.  They are doing it that way because it increases the responsiveness of their UI and increases the scalability of their servers.  You can read more here: http://engineering.linkedin.com/frontend/leaving-jsps-dust-moving-linkedin-dustjs-client-side-templates